# Pass multiple directories to PowerShell

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, arguments

I want to run a PowerShell script and pass working directories via arguments.

The code I have now in VBA:

```vb
strCommand = "powershell.exe -noexit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe -file  `\" &  scriptfolder  & "`\"" output `\""" & sFolder & "`\"" -corefolder `\""" &  Dfd_core & "`\"" -configfolder `\""" &  Dfd_Root & "`\"" -sheetfolder `\""" & dfdsheet & "`\""" 
Set WsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WsShell.Run (strCommand)
```

The code I have in PowerShell:

```
param([String]$output, [String]$corefolder, [String]$configfolder, [String]$sheetfolder)
```

All parameters (output, corefolder, configfolder and sheetfolder) are locations or directories chosen by the user, so they can have spaces inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed your script with double quotes and escape the inner double quotes.
Also, I think you actually want to pass the three parameters to the PowerShell script, and not to the Start-Process command.
Try this:

```
<code>strCommand = "powershell.exe -noexit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe -file  `"" &amp;  scriptfolder  &amp; "`\""" &amp; output &amp; "`\"" -corefolder `\""" &amp;  Dfd_core &amp; "`\"" -configfolder `\""" &amp;  Dfd_Root &amp; "`\"" -sheetfolder `\""" &amp; dfdsheet &amp; "`\"""  Set WsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") WsShell.Run (strCommand)
</code>
```

Comment: It looks like the amp is not a valic syntax in VBA Excel. is there an alternative? @Sh_gosha